ASP.NET Core singleton always get different instances
I am trying to create a global object and need to retain its value through out the whole lifetime.
But I notice the object always get new instance every time when I access it.
The IProfile is not being reference in other place.
 services.AddSingleton<IProfile, Profile>();

 IProfile currentProfile { get; set; }
 private ILogger logger;

 public MainController(IProfile profile, ILogger<MainController> logger)
 {    
     currentProfile = profile;
     logger.LogInformation("IProfile : " + profile.ProfileName);
     this.logger = logger;
 }

 HttpPost("SelectProfile")]
 public async Task<string> SelectProfile(string profile)
 {
     logger.LogInformation(currentProfile.ProfileName);
     logger.LogInformation(currentProfile.GetHashCode().ToString());

     currentProfile = config.Profiles
                            .Where(p => p.ProfileName == profile).FirstOrDefault();

     if (currentProfile.ProfileName is not null)           
         return "Profile Updated";
     
     logger.LogInformation(currentProfile.ProfileName + " " + currentProfile.GetHashCode());

     return ("Profile not found!!");
 }

How to get only one instance in the life time?

Where are you adding the service services.AddSingleton<IProfile, Profile>();? From the code it looks like you're adding it in MainController.  You should be adding it in Program

I am adding this service in the Startup.cs

If it's defined in startup then there will only be one instance available through DI.  A simple way to check the instance of a service is to add a read only Guid Id field and write it the the console every time an instance is created.

It seems you misunderstand how DI and service lifetime work in asp.net core. When you register a service as a singleton using services.AddSingleton<IProfile, Profile>();, it ensures that only one instance of Profile is created and shared throughout the application's lifetime. However, in your code, the line currentProfile = config.Profiles.Where(p => p.ProfileName == profile).FirstOrDefault(); assigns a new instance to currentProfile, which is why you're seeing different instances.

Your profile should be a singleton. You are using GetHashCode() for checking for the same instance. But the documentation is saying:
"...the default implementation of this method must not be used as a unique object identifier for hashing purposes." and the one for ValueType says "If you call the derived type's GetHashCode method, the return value is not likely to be suitable for use as a key in a hash table.".
So better override Equals() and GetHashCode() by yourself - then it will turn out that this is actually the same instance.
Edit #1:
Instances coming from IOptionsMonitor<Configuration> are deserialized from your appsettings.json (or other providers of configurations). So this instances have nothing to do with your Service registrations. So these instances have to be different.

I try to assign a value to the Profile and have ensure the value is assigned successfully.
But when I re access to the object, the value becomes NULL.

Something is missing here: You inject profile and assign it to currentProfile and in your action, you assign  currentProfile again from  config.Profiles. Where are the config coming from? So the config.Profiles could be other instances.

There are a few fields in the Profile object such as ProfileName, Address and etc.
If I assign a value to the profile.ProfileName, the value can retain when I re-access to the object but if I assign the value to the whole object then it will become a new instance instead of updating the existing intance.
currentProfile = config.Profiles.Where........
Since it is initialize as singleton, shouldn't it retain the value even I assign value to the whole object.

It depends  how config.Profiles gets created. So can you show where config.Profiles is created? Only your single Profile class is defined as Singleton.

I get the value of config from the appsettings.
public MainController(IOptionsMonitor<Configuration> config, IProfile profile, ILogger<MainController> logger)
{
    this.config = config.CurrentValue ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));
    currentProfile = profile ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(profile));
    this.logger = logger;
}


Objects coming from IOptionsMonitor<Configuration> are deserialized from your appsettings.json (or other providers of configurations). So this instances have nothing to do with your Service registrations. So these instances have to be different.
